# Height of EasyAutoComplete is limited by div height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, easyautocomplete

I have an EasyAutoComplete which gives City & PostalCode information. This Input is located in a small div, but the EasyAutocomplete window is limited by the height of the div. Only the first element is visible, other elements are not visible. If I enlarge the div, the other elements become visible aswell. So it seems the height of the div limits the EasyAutocomplete window.

[image]

I've tried fixing this with changing the Z-index, but this doesn't seem to work. How can I make it so the Autocomplete is independent of the Div height? It isn't
an option to enlarge the div, so I think the autocomplete needs to become on top of the other elements.

I'll try to work this into an Fiddle, to give a better overview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use easy-autocomplete like below, no need to put data-behavior. Also, you need to override CSS applied by the easy-autocomplete library.

```
.easy-autocomplete{
  height:100% !important
}

.easy-autocomplete input{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! However this doesn't seem to fix the problem, and the Autocomplete is stil not visible. It seems that the height is correct when I inspect this element, so it is more a problem of "priority". I don't want to change the height of the div. Thanks!